# Can I have a list of dictionaries from solving these equations? (Python)

Tags: python, sympy, equation

Here's part of the code I'm working on:

```
delta, beta, gamma = symbols('delta beta gamma')
eq1 = Eq(tan((delta+beta)/2),nz*tan(theta/2))
eq2 = Eq(tan((delta-beta)/2),nx/ny)
eq3 = Eq(cos(gamma/2),cos(theta/2)/cos((delta+beta)/2))
result = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [delta, beta,gamma])
```

All the parameters are given:

```
theta = -1.2974951599797855
nx = - 0.280639152149670
ny = 0.546816938693111
nz = 0.788817407160244
```

Without the equation 3, the output looks like:

```
{delta: -1.01319515173894, beta: -0.0648548698337719}
```

Since there're two values of `gamma`, with eqn 3, the output becomes

```
[(-1.01319515173894, -0.0648548698337719, 0.760927675576123), 
(-1.01319515173894, -0.0648548698337719, 11.8054429387830)]
```

I have two questions about this result: first, is there a way I can make the output looks like a list with two dictionaries? Such as:

```
[{delta: -1.01319515173894, beta: -0.0648548698337719, gamma: 0.760927675576123}, 
{delta:-1.01319515173894, beta: -0.0648548698337719, gamma: 11.8054429387830}]
```

Also, by using `solve`, should I only get the principal angular values? I'm wondering if I could have the second value of `gamma` be `-0.760927675576123`, instead of `11.8054429387830`.

Thanks a lot for the help:)

Comment: `Also, by using solve, should I only get the principal angular values? I'm wondering if I could have the second value of gamma be -0.760927675576123` Can you explain what you mean by the second part? Do you want to replace 11.8 by -0.76? or you are asking something more deeper

Comment: @Akshay Sehgal Thanks a lot for the comment! 11.8 is the radians of angle `gamma`, since it has a periodicity of 2*pi, we could reduce 11.8 to the principal value (which ranges from -pi to pi radians) as -0.76 (They have the same sin and cos values). I'm wondering if I could do that using python.

Comment: You can use `math.remainder` and take a remainder from `tau`, to fix the interval. That would convert 11.8 to -0.76, along with all the other angles. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can turn the list of tuples to list of dicts. To fix interval between -pi and pi, you can use `math.remainder(radian, tau)` (where tau is 2pi) on each angle you get in your output.

```
from math import remainder, tau

#Output radians
output = [(-1.01319515173894, -0.0648548698337719, 0.760927675576123), 
          (-1.01319515173894, -0.0648548698337719, 11.8054429387830)]

#Fix intervals between -pi and pi
fix_interval = [[remainder(j, tau) for j in i] for i in output]

#Convert to dictionary
dict_output = [{'delta':i,'beta':j,'gamma':k} for i,j,k in fix_interval]
dict_output
```

```
[{'delta': -1.01319515173894,
  'beta': -0.0648548698337719,
  'gamma': 0.760927675576123},
 {'delta': -1.01319515173894,
  'beta': -0.0648548698337719,
  'gamma': -0.7609276755761716}]
```

Of course, **you can do it all in one step**, but I have tried keeping it as a separate step so that its easier for you to understand how that's working.